# Word-wrap in org-mode with header specification puts # in front of new line

Tags: org-mode

In org-mode when I specifying the header, like:

```
#-*- mode: org -*-
#+STARTUP: showall
```

Then whenever I have a new line in my outline, it puts a # in front of my new line, like:

```
* Header 1
** Header 2
   Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
   #bla bla
```

How do I prevent this from happing?

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce that. Can you provide your .emacs and your org-mode version?

Comment: I updated my version of the org-mode to 7.5, and now it works.

Comment: please mark this answer as correct for the question not to show on "unanswered" list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated my version of the org-mode to 7.5, and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you can [M-RET in a table cell to split the sentence at point](http://orgmode.org/org.html#index-org_002dM_002dRET_002dmay_002dsplit_002dline-208).